# Any thoughts on how to react to gender-specific language?

Tags: discussion

There have been a couple of times recently when someone has referred to me as "mate" in their comments or responses. I don't tend to be very sensitive about this stuff and have really found very little sexism during my tenure as a computer professional. However, since my Stack Overflow display name is my first name ("Melanie"), I would think it'd be fairly obvious that I'm not a "mate."

I find this amusing more than offensive, but I have been tempted to respond by pointing out my gender.  I don't want to offend anyone else in turn, but I do think people shouldn't automatically assume I'm a guy, even if they don't happen to notice my name.

Thoughts?

Comment: Respond by calling them "lass"? On a more serious note, it might be they didn't notice the name - happens to me sometimes that I don't, even when I'm responding to a comment. But why not point it out, friendly, unless they give reason to think they did it on purpose.

Comment: 'it'd be fairly obvious that I'm not a "mate."' - Obvious to native speakers, not _everyone_. And you are assuming that people noticed your username in the first place...

Comment: @DanielFischer "mate" is fairly commonly used in the UK (even for women sometimes), and I don't think there's anything wrong with it. No idea how it's used in the US though.

Comment: Sounds like a fairly chatty comment - that alone might be reason to flag the comment.

Comment: Good point, Yannis. But how common would it be for a non-native English speaker to use "mate"? Or maybe it's much more common than I think. And yes, Daniel Fischer, I realize they may not have noticed my name; I rarely look at them myself. I guess I just don't want to seem like I have a chip on my shoulder. I like your "lass" suggestion, though. ;)

Comment: @Melanie I don't think there's any slight intended here. I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: @Melanie See Seth's answer. I lived in the UK briefly, and yes it was quite common to call someone "mate", even women. I'm not 100% sure it's gender neutral, but it's certainly not only used for men and you shouldn't take offense. A couple of Australians friends also use it extensively, but I don't remember if they ever used it for women.

Comment: Be thankful you weren't called "mush" :-). In all seriousness though, I wouldn't worry about that too much. I try to avoid gender-specific terms and I know other people do as well. Sometimes people will slip. I would be a lot more worried if people were using derogatory female-specific terminology. You would certainly have a reason to flag the post/comments then. On a side note there are a huge number of usernames on SE that aren't gender specific at all. People try to fudge around it and it becomes habit; sometimes incorrectly.

Comment: IMHO, "mate" is fairly benign. Now, if someone starts out a comment with, "Greetings, my testicle-adorned brother in maleness!"... flag it.

Comment: @Shog9 That's good advice, my testicle-adorned brother in maleness!

Comment: @Shog9 You owe me either a drink or a laptop screen...

Comment: Just a personal interpretation of course, but I have a hunch that quite a few non-native speakers adopt a language they perceive as "cool". Trouble is that being cool is one of the hardest parts of a foreign language and it is easy to sound completely wrong without even knowing it. Again, can't be sure, but I think I have seen it quite often here on SO.

Comment: @Yannis, Okay, I had no idea. To me (from the US) it sounds like something you'd call a man only. Live and learn.

Comment: @Yannis: yeah mate, us Aussies do use it quite a bit. In my experience, we often include women among our "mates" (i.e. friends), but would less often refer to a woman as "mate". That said, no-one would think it improper if you did refer to a woman with "mate".

Comment: The *literal* meaning of "mate" is not gender-specific. I'm not sure what that means for the common colloquial usage; it's not part of my particular dialect.

Comment: Even though the word "mate" can be used with regard to women, this question is more general than that. Even simple pronouns are gender-sensitive and often used wrongly.

Comment: @Melanie, yes, I understand that (my attempts at humor are apparently falling flat today), I was just trying to say you should not bother with that kind of thing, at least not on the SE network. The language barrier is a common source of misunderstanding, and English is not the native language of *many* users (including yours truly). When in doubt, assume no harm was meant.

Comment: @Monolo This. Picking up a language without being introduced to it in your childhood results in adopting a lot of mangled colloquialisms. One of which might be the misuse of "mate" for women.

Comment: @FredericHamidi - yeah, I understand. I am assuming no harm. My real concern is whether I should point it out and risk offending someone else. But now, since it seems that in at least some parts of the world "mate" can be used for both men and women, this becomes a true non-issue. But if any of youse ever Shog9's suggestion with me, watch out! ;)

Comment: @KeithThompson Speaking on behalf of people from NZ, Australia, and the UK: when the word 'mate' is used it is a colloquialism that is gender neutral, although it is more frequently used by males when referring to other male friends (women don't tend to use it so much unless they are the beer-swilling trailor-park dwelling types).

Comment: If they not notice your name, consider to place a photo of you on the thumbnail.

Comment: +1 for doing something that I've never seen before: asking a gender-related question here in a constructive way!

Comment: @Aristos - that's a good idea. I'm so tempted to use Catwoman. And that wouldn't be sexist, right? I guess I'll just have to find a picture of li'l ol' me. :)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I've had people use *he*, *him*, and *his* in comments referring to me ("Kate made some good points in his answer" or "The OP says he tried that" when I'm the OP) and I usually do nothing about it at all. There are names out there that I can't map to genders (sure, aliases and made-up names, but even when people are using the names given to them by their parents, if they're from a different culture I may not know) and statistically, most posters here are male. I do correct it when I think it's relevant, or if I happen to be commenting anyway.

If I can edit it (an answer rather than a comment, and I have the rep on that site) I sometimes will. If it's a comment and I was going to comment anyway, I may include a "btw, it was her answer, not his" or "btw, I'm she, not he" but then again I may not. When it's a comment, I usually don't do anything.

I treat "mate" as a gender neutral word. Australians have most definitely called me it when they know my gender. So I wouldn't worry about that one. [To be clear, I mean that entirely literally. That is one I wouldn't worry about. I know there's an idiom that starts "I wouldn't X" that means "don't X" - I'm not telling anyone that. People react to things the way they react to things, and I wouldn't say anyone was wrong to feel odd being called a "wrong" name or pronoun.]

Comment: Actually, in some languages (like Chinese iirc) they don't have a gender difference. There is only one word for person, so everyone to them is a "he, him" etc. That could be a language barrier.

Comment: I just use "OP" and "they".

Comment: Me! I'm a good example of this -- I've walked into more than one interview and had the interviewer later mention that they had assumed I was a dude until meeting me. My name is rather obviously female *in the context of its culture of origin*. To Westerners, it (apparently) is assumed to be a masculine name.

Comment: @Aarthi - That's interesting, I would have guessed female without looking at your user icon, but I wouldn't have been sure, so wouldn't have assumed either way. In general I find it easier to assume a gender neutral stance on the internet, since even if someone is presenting themselves as one gender it doesn't mean that's who they are.

Comment: Kate, one other thing to note is that with a name like yours there are a number of intersecting cultural conventions, such as Family name being first or last [depending on culture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_name) and whether a stranger is called by first or last name. As such, it is possible that the commenter assumed that *Kate* was your family name, thus *Gregory* must be your given name, hence assuming you are male. The Internet really is a melting pot of cultures, so I think the maxim of "be liberal in what you accept and strict in what you send" works well at so many levels.

Comment: @Aarthi Who said "dude" was for guys only :P (I've heard many girls call each other that.. could be a locality difference).

Comment: FTR, I reckon that whole trailing parenthetical could be avoided by injecting "personally" before "I wouldn't worry" ;)

Comment: @ColeJohnson referring to someone in the plural is awkward at best

Comment: @RichardU "they" _can_ be singular: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they

Comment: Hey @RichardU go have your "they isn't singular" argument on someone else's answer. I never mentioned singular they and don't need a storm of unrelated comments on my answer.

Comment: @KateGregory have a lovely day.

Answer (score 38):

"Mate" is also used as a [Colloquialism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colloquialism) to mean "friend" "buddy", "coworker" etc.

Of course, it *might not* have been used in this way for you, but without context I'd say it was just a friendly informal way of saying "buddy".

[Dictionary.com says](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mate) "mate" can mean

> An associate; fellow worker; comrade; partner (often used in combination): classmate; roommate.

Comment: "Comrade" would be a good gender-neutral way to address fellow users on the SE network.

Comment: I agree. As an added bonus, it would tend to calm all of those annoying comparisons to the USSR.

Comment: @Shog9 Or exacerbate them.

Comment: Right. I'm not saying something else wouldn't have been better, just that I think that this is the way it was meant.

Comment: @Monolo I dare you to try that on [Politics.SE](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions) ;)

Comment: @Yannis at Politics, they should call each other "Parteigenosse"

Answer (score 21):

## Ignore it completely

In the big scheme of things I think that the "focus on the content and not the user" mindset needs to come into play here. It *really* doesn't matter if the OP/commenter/answerer/flagger/spammer/editor/voter calls you he, she or [it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSPII.jpg), the thing that matters is [*what* they are saying](http://youtu.be/0Rl9Cxc7uZA?t=25s).

I've been called "dear" on numerous occasions around the network. This is not something that me, as a native English speaker, would expect to hear in a (somewhat) formal interaction. However, the correct approach is to simply ignore this
(perceived) error. Remember that Stack Overflow (and the internet at large) is filled with many many many people that do not share the same culture or language. Things get lost in translation. Google translate gets lost in translation...

In some languages, the masculine plural form of a noun is also sometimes used as a non-specific gender. In Hebrew, for example, when talking (in the second person) about a group of people,

- a group of males will have one form of noun - אתם
- a group of females will have one form of noun - אתן
- a group of mixed gender will be referred to using the same form as a group of males - אתם

Taking into consideration these types of differences, I really think things like this should be skimmed over allowing you to **concentrate on exactly *what* is being said and not necessarily *how* they are saying it**.

Comment: Thanks, dear. ;) No, really, I do appreciate your comments.

Comment: It's very important for communities like SO to be mindful of the fact that not all techies are men.  English is one of many languages in the unfortunate position that gender neutrality does not come automatically in speech.

Comment: @dje - how do you suggest we be mindful of every single culture that visits the site? At the end of the day (in my examples), no insult was insinuated, it's simply a mis-communication - and it doesn't at all affect content of the question/answer. Therefore it should be ignored as anything not related to the issue is just noise...

Comment: @djechlin All the more reason to ignore it! Most of the time the user isn't trying to be rude, they just don't know better.

Comment: @Seth per my answer it's very often possibly to discreetly and germanely suggest they use gender-neutral language, which is consistent with SO's culture of education.

Comment: @Lix I didn't say every culture.  "Men" and "women" are two major groups worth being mindful of.  Certainly in America and to varying (sometimes greater) extents in other countries there is a gender gap in technology that is exacerbated by community culture, and it is important SO be on the right side of this.  Yes, I am suggesting that gendered pronouns are a not insignificant exacerbating force, but if this strikes you as too trivial I don't expect to change any minds in these here comments.

Comment: @djechlin That doesn't matter. If I come across it in an answer or question I will change it as a matter of correcting grammar, but I don't think it's a big deal and should be ignored on the more general side of things.

Comment: @Seth Yes, that's consistent with what I'm saying - in cases of gendered pronouns polite, discreet corrections are a proper response.  This is, literally, not ignoring it, and I'm not suggesting calling the PC police more dramatically is a proper response.  (See:  so-called "Donglegate.")

Comment: @dje - with regard to the "greater good", I think that it is important to take a stand against stereotypes. I myself have several female programmers in my professional and personal life so I could be the first to say that the stereotype of males in the IT industry is unjust at the very least. As far as the site goes, again, with the focus being on the content, these issues are really irrelevant.

Comment: Posts can be edited, but comments can't, so we'll be stuck with this issue for now, but unless there is some open sexism that should be flagged, mistakes stemming from cultural or language differences simply can not be remedied with our current toolbox.

Comment: At the risk of veering further off topic, I will say one of the values of SE is developing good communication skills, i.e. the "how," in all our users, see e.g. [Jeff's post here.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/02/how-to-write-without-writing.html). You could argue that gendering ambiguous users distracts from content, so correcting users when consistent with our toolbox is consistent with improving content.  I agree comments are murky - the one time this has come up for me I corrected in reply but on another day might have just ignored.

Comment: Hopefully lastly I will say that now that I reflect on your answer differently, you are kind of saying that the user who uses a gendered word may be coming from an ESL culture in which the user's primary language treats gender differently.  While we're not here to teach people English IMO I would find that change worth correcting in a post, but yes it behooves the reader to bear in mind the user may have a legitimate reason to "not know any better."

Comment: English uses the male pronoun to refer to both sexes when not in conflict with the context.

Comment: @LanceRoberts ...but this is nearly fully accepted as outdated and mildly sexist.  See, e.g., [any style guide.](http://www.copydesk.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1002)

Answer (score 18):

Just ignore it if it bothers you.

First of all, "mate" is not male-specific.

Secondly, accidentally referring to you with a male-targeted greeting rather than a female-targeted greeting is not "sexism". Sexism is when you wilfully deny rights to, or consider inferior, a person based solely on their gender. This has nothing to do with that at all. Let's stop bandying that word around willy-nilly please.

Comment: Sometimes I wish I could give an answer +10...

Comment: On reflection, I really need to point out that this answer is wrong. When someone calls me "he" it's partly because they think that everyone here is male. That tells those who aren't that we don't really belong. And that can be harmful. While willfully denying someone rights or treating them as inferior is sexist, that is not a complete list of all the sexist behaviours that exist.

Comment: @KateGregory While I _do_ sympathise, and I wish people wouldn't assume that "he" is accurate (much like I wish people wouldn't assume that everybody they're talking to in English is an American), and although my view on this may have softened in the intervening half-decade, I still can't bring myself to classify it as "sexism" - as ignorance, though, yes! I maintain that there's not much to do but ignore it, although a swift "I am not a 'he'" response probably wouldn't be uncalled for... And, back to the question at hand, I definitely maintain that "mate" is usually not male-specific.

Comment: @KateGregory Interestingly, by total co-incidence I just followed a link from Meta to [this SE blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/02/21/new-question-answer-rate-limits/) which contains the text _"Wow. How bored is this guy? (And yeah, it’s always a guy, who are we kidding.)"_ If it's not cool to assume that everybody's a guy, then it's also not cool to assume that all troublemakers are guys. We might want to look into getting that fixed for a more consistent approach!

Answer (score 18):

To back up Kate Gregory's point about Australians, I live in Australia and we use 'mate' for everyone.  Men, women, kids, cops, strangers, bosses, parents, animals, etc.

Traditionally it was more of a male term but these days that gender split is long gone with most people.

Its meaning is usually somewhere between friend/buddy and a comma/exclamation mark.

[image: g'day mate]
https://twitter.com/alexvitlin/status/709551328297529345

Answer (score 5):

Presuming "he" is a bigger issue but I think I've actually only seen that maybe twice in the last year on SO.  In the case of a question or answer I'll edit it to be gender neutral, which insofar as edits are germane and tactful is a germane and tactful way to remind the OP of this consideration, and in the case of one comment I replied in comment and the original commenter addressed it.  For the scale of the non-gender-neutral pronoun problem on SO this approach seems perfectly sufficient to keep the community aware (or PC, although I'm not sure calling this PC is PC? etc.)

As far as "mate" is concerned I think it happens in a context of an in my experience good track record on gender-awareness in SO, e.g., if the user who said it meant it in a gendered way, that user probably uses the word "he" presumptively, but this habit would have probably been corrected fairly quickly.  So I wouldn't worry about it.  I'm leery to suggest someone "not worry about" something as sensitive as gender sensitivity in technology, but at some point it's necessary to take a stance as a community member, so I'd like to hear more information from the OP or more evidence that "mate" is skewed.

Comment: What is "PC" in this context? [Political correct](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/politically_correct#Adjective)?

Comment: Yes [. . . . . . . ]

Answer (score 2):

Its a cultural thing. Here in Australia I get called mate, cobber and even Digger (term for a 1st world war Australian or New Zealand soldier) by people I may know personally or by strangers I have an interaction with i.e. trades people. To me its a respectful word identifying me as someone the other person trusts. If the term mate is commonly used in that way in your neck of the woods and the tone is polite then its cool otherwise perhaps just remind the person of your name and they should get it.

Comment: In an international setting like that of the SE sites, certain expressions that may imply familiarity should be possibly be avoided. A few times I had to reply to someone addressing me as "mate" that I'm not their mate (I could probably be their father), and that addressing random people on the internet with certain terms may annoy or offend them.

Answer (score 1):

My thoughts on this topic in the past have considered whether the speaker, assuming his interlocutor to be male, is exhibiting subconscious biases that are partly responsible for the gender skew in the IT industry in the first place. I tend to take the view that speakers who use male-specific language can be (gently) re-educated, just in the same way help-vampires can be encouraged to write better questions.

I see this behaviour in questions frequently, and generally I try to edit it out; I see [you guys](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22you+guys%22) a lot, with [dudes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22dudes%22) and "mate" much less so. I'll digress from the consensus here and venture to say that, if these words are becoming *less* gender specific, they haven't achieved it entirely. From a British perspective, the use of "mate" to refer to a woman is fine from a speaker of either gender if he/she knows her well, but otherwise (for me at least) some gender specificity still lingers. On Stack Overflow, where discussion parcipants don't know each other, I think it sticks out like a huge sore thumb; after all, this is a professional resource site, not a chat room.

As someone else says here, I would balance this issue with a sensitivity to people whose first language is not English, and who may just be occasionally selecting a clumsy word.

What to do? Well, if it is persistent, you could try explaining the issue to the speaker, so long as it is clear they are not struggling with their English. Also, there are various guides on "how to ask technical questions" around the web, and I think it would be a positive step if they could touch on this. I've [included it in mine](http://blog.jondh.me.uk/2012/09/how-to-use-stack-overflow/) already.

Comment: I strongly disagree with some of the points in your technical guide. For instance, `Downvoting answers on questions you have asked yourself can come across as ingratitude` is not correct.

Comment: @Knights: I'll happily hear any feedback you have to offer, and will be pleased to make edits. The issue you raise is connected to the broader topic of civility, which as you'll know is hotly contested around these parts. I don't share your certainty that my statement is _categorically_ incorrect, but nevertheless will consider amending if you would amplify your views on it. (Happy to discuss here, but it may be a little O/T - perhaps via email or as a comment on my blog?)

Comment: Sure! I'm a litle busy at the moment, so I can't go on chat, but I'll be available later.

Comment: Sorry, I was quite busy. I'll send you an email at some point - though I may forget. If I do, feel free to nudge me!

Comment: @Knights, ping `:)`. If you are pressed for time, could you perhaps take just the above item (about downvoting on one's own question) and drop a comment on the article directly? This will offer to readers a second opinion, to which I'll respond from an anti-snark perspective - I am sure new Stackers would benefit from that discourse.

Comment: Ah, sorry! I have indeed been busy. I still do plan to send you a response. I'll try to do that in the next few days.

Comment: Thanks @Knights, no rush at all. Put it in your calendar for a lazy Sunday or something `:)`.

Comment: Wow, I feel bad about this. I'd totally forgotten about it. Would feedback still be helpful?

Comment: @Emrakul: ha, no worries! Yes, feel free. My blog is open for comments all the time, and I'm always interested in feedback on anything I post.